# Is there a free, open-source question and answer (Q&A) application similar to StackExchange?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, qa

I'm launching a Q&A site similar to StackExchange.

Does anyone have any recommendations for free self-hosted Q&A software that is easy to customize?

I've seen [this wordpress theme](http://templatic.com/cms-themes/answers) but it isn't free and, therefore, isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: I would like to see more PHP/MySQL technology

Answer (score 12):

[OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/) is also a nice implementation and is relatively easy to get up and running. What I don't like about it is how close it is to SE sites as far as design. Granted, its hard to come up with a better interface, but hopefully you make your's a little more unique :)

This is also GPL, so it's free as in freedom and free as in free beer.

Its written in Python/Django and should work even on the most basic shared web hosting.

Comment: OSQA looks like a perfect match, but its written in Python. I am not sure if i can install it in my Apache server with MySQl.

Comment: @daron - it should go right in .. are you self hosted or using someone else?

Comment: yes it will be self hosted

Comment: While I recommend not using mod_python .. there are a few ways to get it to work.

Comment: I will check and see if support guy can install python on my server. Its not installed for now

Comment: @daron - its almost obligatory .. python is likely there, its a matter of how your web server sees (and runs) it. (assuming GNU/Linux hosting)

Comment: Can this work on Windows IIS and SqlServer also? I have not read visited the site, just need to know incase...

Comment: Relevant link (and also shameless self-promotion which I swear is merely a side effect): http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1541/how-to-install-osqa-q-and-a-application-in-apache

Comment: QSQA ist a nice and fast solution which I would prefer. If you use IIS, take a look at the answer from theycallmemorty. The tool he suggested is written in asp.net.

Answer (score 8):

Since you are using PHP/MySQL, I'd recommend [Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/). I've used it and I really like it. Although the default interface isn't as polished as Stack Overflow, it's still better than the other PHP Q&A apps I've seen.

Comment: That actually looks rather neat :) +1

Comment: The interface was not that great. i am not sure how far we can go for customizing it.

Comment: You can customize every aspect of the layout/style without much difficulty, see http://www.question2answer.org/advanced.php#theme-advanced. The developer is really helpful too if you have questions.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Stacked](http://code.google.com/p/stacked/), an open source implementation of a Q&A site like Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

MSO has [a huge list.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

Answer (score 2):

There are some pretty nice options available to you when it comes to Open Source, I've listed the best 3 that I'm aware of below for you:

- **[OSQA](http://www.osqa.net)** is an open source Q&A platform similar to StackExchange, definitely worth looking at if you're considering open source.
- **Askbot** is also a Python Django platform modeled on StackExchange, so should be considered as well
- **Django Brainstorm** is again, a Python Django based platform developed by Sunlight Labs and can do the job also

You may also want to consider a SaaS solution if you're considering open source, as these solutions are automatically updated/updated/supported and require much less maintenance...but of course you have to pay for those perks:)  Here is a list of powerful SaaS solutions that are also available for consideration.

- **[Answerbase.com](http://www.answerbase.com)** is a good service supporting some brand-name customers, serving a few different markets when it comes to Q&A interaction, worth looking at.
- **Qhub.com** provides a nice Q&A community platform, very user-friendly and a nice Web 2.0 look/feel.
- **Shapado.com** offers a clean Q&A experiece for either a community or for enterprises looking for internal collaboration.

Good luck with your Q&A community/platform:)