# How to Install OSQA Q and A application in Apache

Tags: deployment, web-platform-installer

How to Install OSQA Q and A application in Apache Server. I have mod_python installed but still I am not able to run OSQA. I could not find the easy instruction to install it.

Comment: I really think you'd have a better chance at an answer on http://meta.osqa.net/questions/
I know I'm asking the same thing there, but regarding nginx :)

Answer (score 7):

OSQA is a Django application, so first you will need to install [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com). You may also need to install other dependencies of the project. (I tried it and had to install [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/), for example) Also, I would *strongly* recommend uninstalling mod_python (unless you really need it for something else) and installing [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) instead, since as far as I know mod_python is deprecated and on its way to being completely unmaintained.

Once you have mod_wsgi installed and enabled in the Apache configuration, you'll need to use the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive to enable OSQA.

1. When you check out OSQA from SVN, you'll have a directory named `trunk` which contains a file called `osqa.wsgi.dist`. Move that `trunk` directory to a location of your choice, probably in the same place you store other website files.
2. Make sure all files in `trunk` (or whatever you renamed it to) are readable by the web server. (They probably already are)
3. Read through the file `settings_local.py.dist` and alter it to suit your needs. You'll at least need to provide a database name and database engine.
4. Rename `settings_local.py.dist` to `settings_local.py`.
5. Rename `osqa.wsgi.dist` to `osqa.wsgi`.
6. In your Apache configuration file, inside the virtual host from which you want OSQA to be served, add the following snippet (modified as described below, of course):

   ```
   <IfModule wsgi_module>
       WSGIScriptAlias /osqa /var/www/www.example.com/osqa.wsgi
   </IfModule>
   ```

   Here `/osqa` should be the URL path under which you want OSQA to be available (it could be `/` if you like), and `/var/www/www.example.com/osqa.wsgi` should be replaced with the full path to the file `osqa.wsgi` (the one you renamed in the previous step).
7. Check your Apache configuration and if everything is OK, reload Apache. You should be able to access OSQA at your chosen URL. If anything goes wrong, the error message should give you the information you need to fix it.

Comment: +1 - This is exactly the kind of fast and comprehensive help I hoped this site would provide to people.