# looking for a Q and A tool with payment for answer

Tags: looking-for-a-script, qa

I would like to include an expert Q and A system into my site that works like stackoverflow but also gives the user the option to promise money for the answer.

Comment: related: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/is-there-a-free-open-source-question-and-answer-qa-application-similar-to-st

Comment: What exactly does promising money entail in your mind as a feature? I "promise" you ten bucks if you respond to this comment. See? Now any Q&A system can handle your request.

Comment: @Su' - every +1 is funded from upvoter financial account, -1 - from answerer, accept - from asker. Just idea of real interst instead of child toys with "leagues"

Comment: @LazyBadger that actually sounds like an interesting idea.

Comment: however, I was more thinking along the lines of involving experts like lawyers, doctors etc. that would not want to give away their knowledge for free.

Comment: Of course, I could set a fixed price for asking a question but I am expecting different questions of varying difficulty to be asked so I would like users themselves to decide what an answer would be worth to them

Comment: FYI, there are already a few sites like this. Most of these are very large sites using a custom developed web application. The cheapest solution would be modify an open source Q&A platform to integrate payment processing into it. You'd need web development experience (or hire a developer) + a merchant account and subscription to a payment gateway.

Comment: Promising payment? You mean like oDesk or any other freelance website where people post projects and offer to pay 0% upfront until the project is completed successfully? Just a suggestion you better make sure to take the promised payment from the asker put the money into an escrow account and release it to the person with the best answer. This way people will actually want to answer questions. Otherwise you're going to be competing with the SO network plus the older generation of paid sites who have a strong user base. Unless some how you have a really unique idea

Comment: @Su' - It would be easy enough to work. Upon asking a question, the asker deposits the nominal funds into the 'website' bank account. After x time if there are no satisfactory answers, money is refunded. You could bring in a community aspect for them to vote on answers etc with a rep system giving more/less leverage to respected users etc... Quite why anyone would pay for knowledge online, I'm not sure. You can research or answer most questions for free (thanks to sites like the Stack Exchange network!).

Answer (score 1):

[OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/) is an excellent Q&A that you may consider. I'm not sure wheather it has bulit-in capability to 'pay for answers'. However since it based on Django framework, you can extend and add features if you are familiar with Django.

Answer (score 0):

Q&A - It's a Wordpress plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qa/

Comment: I see no evidence of a "payment for answers" feature(whatever that might mean, as per my comment above). Can you expand on this suggestion?

Comment: The "payment for answer" part is something he'll have to implement. And my guess is that he wanted to implement something close to this: https://learnable.com/

Comment: actually I am looking for a system like justanswer.com (just simpler)